# Assigning colors in array to objects in p5.js/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to assign each colour of my c[] array of colours to each of my       six Orb objects. My loop just assigns all the colours to all of the     objects. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
var orb = [];
var c = ["#C460E0", 
         "#F469A9", 
         "#69F5E7", 
         "#687DF2", 
         "#69F591",             
         "#F1Ea67"];
var col;
var num;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        orb[i] = new SoftOrb();
}

function draw() {
    background(1);
    for (var i = 0; i < orb.length; i++) {

        orb[i].colour(); // <-----???!
        orb[i].edges();
        orb[i].display();
        orb[i].move();
    }
}

function SoftOrb() {
    this.loc = createVector(random(width), random(height));
    this.vel = createVector(0, 0);

    this.col = col;
    this.display = function() {
        ellipse(this.loc.x, this.loc.y, 100, 100);
    }
    this.colour = function() {
        noStroke();
        for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
            var index = c.indexOf(j);
            fill(c[j]);
        }
```

Comment: So what you expect to happen and what actually happens? You have 2 `{` missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Fix your syntax. You're missing closing curly brackets at the end of your code. Hopefully this is just a copy-paste error. But be careful with those, because they make it harder to answer you!

**Step 2:** You need to pass the color from the `c` array into the `SoftOrb` constructor. That might look like this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    orb[i] = new SoftOrb(c[i]);
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** You need to modify your `SoftOrb` constructor to actually accept the color argument.

```
function SoftOrb(col) {
```

You're already doing the assignment of `this.col = col;` so now `col` is a specific color for a specific `SoftOrb`.

**Step 4:** Now you just need to use `col` to set the color.

```
  this.colour = function() {
    noStroke();
    fill(col);
  }
```

Note that you could just move this into the `display()` function, but that's more personal preference than anything.

**Step 5:** After you fix that, you'll still get errors because the `edges()` and `move()` functions don't exist. Get rid of them to test that your colors work before trying to move on to coding the next thing.

Comment: please fix the typo (fro mthe → from the)

Comment: Thanks so much Kevin Workman, yes it was a paste typo on the brackets. Its all working now. Cheers!